# My website is showing "Hello World" on every other device but on my computer it's showing advertisement

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel

My website was showing advertisement for me so i contacted some people to help me.They all said that they see "Hello World" on my website whilst i see this[image]

What may be the problem?
My domain registrar is GoDaddy.My NS Records were not changed and by Default are

```
A   @   160.153.161.239 600 seconds
A   admin   160.153.161.239 600 seconds Edit
A   mail    160.153.161.239 600 seconds Edit
CNAME   autoconfig  @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   autoconfig.admin    @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   autodiscover    @   600 seconds Edit
CNAME   autodiscover.admin  @   600 seconds Edit
CNAME   cpanel  @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   webdisk @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   webdisk.admin   @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   webmail @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   whm @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   www @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   www.admin   @   1 Hour  Edit
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour
```

And my website's IP address 160.153.161.239

Comment: It looks like you can't log into your other account anymore?   I marked your other question from your other account as a duplicate of this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107332/my-website-is-not-showing-files-i-uploaded-even-after-24-hours?noredirect=1

Comment: As I asked in the other question, please edit in your DNS records.  Nameserver (NS), A, and CNAME.

Comment: If the problem is just on your computer it could also be something in your hosts.txt (or /etc/hosts) file.   Have you modified that on your local computer?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i have edited my Nameservers.What should i put in A and CNAME.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no it's not only on my computer but my phone and other computer also.

Comment: Who is your domain registrar?   What did you put in the settings for the NS records?   Who is your DNS host?   What did you put in the settings for A or CNAME?   Who is your web host?   What is the IP address of your site?   Add all that info to your question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i added all the info i could,some of it may be wrong because it's my first time buying domain,so i would be more than happy to fix it.

Comment: You have the TTL set to 600 seconds (1 hour now).   Future changes to DNS should only take that long to propagate.   It is possible that your old TTL setting was higher.   Possibly up to 3 days.   It can take up to 3 days for all computers on the internet to get the correct IP address for your website if the TTL was set high.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller but i haven't changed anything.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller can the problem be with my wifi router? While as i was away on 3G i opened my website on my phone and it showed "Hello World" but when i came back it showed advertisement again.

Comment: Could be.   It looks like either something is caching old DNS entries from domain parking, or maybe the router has a virus.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i doubt it's because of caching.I have got a chrome extension that prevents caches and also i have tried it in ingocnito window.

Comment: A chrome extension isn't going to help with a DNS cache on your router or from your ISP.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I guess i should reset the router and wait for one more day and if nothing happens contact them again

Comment: The Hello World is now showing.

Comment: @Anaksunaman i know but it's not showing on my devices

Answer (score 2):

> "While as I was away on 3G I opened my website on my phone and it showed "Hello World" but when I came back it showed the advertisement again.

This statement, and fact that everyone else can see the updated content, leads me to believe this is almost definitely a local network issue (that is, not related to the registrar).

Since you are apparently not hosting the site locally, I would:

- Try a separate (brand new) browser other than Chrome on the local network. Your anti-page caching extension(s) may not be working correctly.
- Triple check the router. Many do DNS caching to cut down on traffic so this very well could be an issue.
- Try a different set of DNS servers for the local network. If the issue is due to ISP DNS caching, you might be a out of luck until they decide to update that information. However, you can use free DNS servers such as Google DNS (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4) in your router settings to help test this.

[image: Google DNS Settings]

Regardless of anything else, from a DNS perspective, I would use the lowest possible cache times in my DNS records as possible.

Comment: It got fixed.I think it just needed some time to get on all computers.But thanks for your asnwer!

Comment: Welcome. Glad that it's working for you now. =)